# In Mathematica, what does @@@ mean?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I've been working through problems on [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/), and some of the solutions that other people have posted use a triple-at-sign, i.e. '@@@'.  In the help browser for v7, I find an entry for @@ (which says it's the infix version of 'Apply') but none for @@@.  What does it mean?

EDIT:  Here's an example, which I think I can post without violating the spirit of Project Euler:

```
bloc[n_, f_][t_] := {f @@@ #, #~Tr~f} & /@ Join @@ Partition[t, {n, n}, 1];
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As others have noted, `@@@` is, technically, shorthand for `Apply` with an optional third argument, as is explained deep in the [documentation for `Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html).

But I like to think of

```
f @@@ {{a,b}, {c,d}, {e,i}}
```

as shorthand for

```
f @@#& /@ {{a,b} {c,d}, {e,i}}
```

In other words, take a pure function (shorthand: `...#...&`) that does an `Apply` (shorthand: `@@`) to a list of arguments, and `Map` (shorthand: `/@`) that over a list of such lists of arguments.
The result is

```
{f[a,b], f[c,d], f[e,i]}
```

Comment: I had to run that a few ways before it made sense!  But you're right, that does seem like the most natural interpretation.

Answer (score 12):

@@@ is the short form for Apply at level 1.

```
f @@@ {{a, b, c}, {d, e}}
```

is equivalent to

```
Apply[f, {{a, b, c}, {d, e}}, {1}]
```

Reference: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html

You may need to expand the Scope and Level Specification sections.

Answer (score 8):

> f @@@ expr is equivalent to Apply[f, expr, {1}].

[documents.wolfram.com](http://documents.wolfram.com/mathematica/functions/Apply)