# Replacing commas in list with arrow ->

Tags: list, replace, wolfram-mathematica

How do I replace the commas on the second level of a list with replacement arrows?

For example, this:

```
{{a, girl}, {b, girl}, {c, girl}, {e, girl}, {g, girl}}
```

To this:

```
{{a->girl}, {b->girl}, {c->girl}, {e->girl}, {g->girl}}
```

`Replace` doesn't work because it thinks the comma shouldn't be there. Putting it in quotes doesn't work, nor does `StringReplace`

What I think it should be:

```
Replace[list, "," -> "->", {2}]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following gives the desired result:

```
lop = {{a, girl}, {b, girl}, {c, girl}, {e, girl}, {g, girl}} (* list o' pairs *)

{#1 -> #2}& @@@ lop
```

To me that's the most natural way to do it.
Here's another way that avoids the use of a lambda function:

```
List /@ Rule @@@ lop
```

More on that way of using `@@@`: [In Mathematica, what does @@@ mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141166)

If you don't like `@@@` you can do this:

```
{First@# -> Last@#}& /@ lop
```

And here's yet another way, using a replacement rule:

```
lop /. {x_,y_}->{x->y}
```

And, what the heck, here's the least intuitive way I can think of to do it:

```
Transpose@{Thread[Rule@@Transpose[lop]]}
```

(Note that `/.` is shorthand for `ReplaceAll`, `/@` is shorthand for `Map`, `@@` is shorthand for `Apply`, and `f@x` is just another way to write `f[x]`.)

Comment: There's an even cleaner way of doing it: `Composition[List, Rule] @@@ lop`

Answer (score 4):

```
{{a, girl}, {b, girl}, {c, girl}, {e, girl}, {g, girl}}/.{x_, y_} -> {Rule[x,y]}
```

Result:

```
{{a -> girl}, {b -> girl}, {c -> girl}, {e -> girl}, {g -> girl}}
```

These things are explained under the tutorials for patterns and transformation rules in the help system.

HTH!

**Edit**

You CAN do it by using Strings  ... but it is not the right way:

```
x = ToString[{{a, girl}, {b, girl}, {c, girl}, {e, girl}, {g, girl}}];
y = StringReplace[x, "{" ~~ d_ ~~ ", " ~~ Shortest[f__] ~~ "}" -> 
                     "{" ~~ d ~~ "->" ~~ f ~~ "}"];
z = ToExpression@y
```

**Edit 2**

The `List[]` and the `Sequence[]` are two constructs that you must understand to start working with Mathematica.

Replacing the braces or the comma in a List is not possible, because `List[]` is a function and the `{..,..,..,..}` is just notation.

Try the following to understand it:

```
 {{a,b},{c,d}} //FullForm
```

and

```
{a, b} /. List -> Plus
```

Answer (score 1):

`MapApply` works nicely here:

```
In[1]:= Rule @@@ {{a, girl}, {b, girl}, {c, girl}, {e, girl}, {g, girl}}

Out[1]= {a -> girl, b -> girl, c -> girl, e -> girl, g -> girl}
```

Comment: Oops, thank you!  This works then: `List/@Rule @@@ {{a, girl}, {b, girl}, {c, girl}, {e, girl}, {g, girl}}`