# Passing parameters stored in a list to expression

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How can I pass values to a given expression with several variables? The values for these variables are placed in a list that needs to be passed into the expression.

Answer (score 15):

Your revised question is straightforward, simply

```
f @@ {a,b,c,...} == f[a,b,c,...]
```

where `@@` is shorthand for [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html?q=Apply&lang=en).  Internally, `{a,b,c}` is `List[a,b,c]` (which you can see by using [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullForm.html?q=FullForm&lang=en) on any expression), and `Apply` just replaces the [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Head.html?q=Head&lang=en), `List`, with a new `Head`, `f`, changing the function.  The operation of `Apply` is not limited to lists, in general

```
f @@ g[a,b] == f[a,b]
```

Also, look at [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sequence.html?q=Sequence&lang=en) which does

```
f[Sequence[a,b]] == f[a,b]
```

So, we could do this instead

```
f[ Sequence @@ {a,b}] == f[a,b]
```

which while pedantic seeming can be very useful.

**Edit**: `Apply` has an optional 2<sup>nd</sup> argument that specifies a level, i.e.

```
Apply[f, {{a,b},{c,d}}, {1}] == {f[a,b], f[c,d]}
```

Note: the shorthand for `Apply[fcn, expr,{1}]` is `@@@`, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141166/in-mathematica-what-does-mean), but to specify any other level description you need to use the full function form.

Answer (score 4):

A couple other ways...

1. Use rule replacement

   `f /. Thread[{a,b} -> l]`

   (where `Thread[{a,b} -> l]` will evaluate into `{a->1, b->2}`)
2. Use a pure function

   `Function[{a,b}, Evaluate[f]] @@ l`

   (where `@@` is a form of Apply[] and `Evaluate[f]` is used to turn the function into `Function[{a,b}, a^2+b^2]`)

Comment: Yeah. We could write a blog: The 1001 ways to get the `SquaredEuclideanDistance[ ]` without mentioning it. :D

Comment: I avoided mentioning Dot[l,l] b/c I figured it was a bit too tuned to the specifics of the question...

Comment: @Brett See my answer. I wasn't ashamed to suggest `l.l` :D

Comment: @Belisarius  Why'd you leave out `z = Complex @@ l;z*Conjugate[z]`?  (And if we get to 1001, do we win a prize, or get kicked out?) :-)

Answer (score 3):

For example, for two elements

```
f[l_List]:=l[[1]]^2+l[[2]]^2
```

for any number of elements

```
g[l_List] := l.l
```

or

```
h[l_List]:= Norm[l]^2
```

So:

```
Print[{f[{a, b}], g[{a, b}], h[{a, b}]}]

{a^2 + b^2, a^2 + b^2, Abs[a]^2 + Abs[b]^2}
```

Two more, just for fun:

```
i[l_List] := Total@Table[j^2, {j, l}]

j[l_List] := SquaredEuclideanDistance[l, ConstantArray[0, Length[l]]
```

**Edit**

Regarding your definition

```
f[{__}] = a ^ 2 + b ^ 2;
```

It has a few problems:

1) You are defining a constant, because the `a,b` are not parameters.
2) You are defining a function with Set, Instead of SetDelayed, so the evaluation is done immediately. Just try for example

```
 s[l_List] = Total[l]
```

vs. the right way:

```
 s[l_List] := Total[l]
```

which remains unevaluated until you use it.

3) You are using a pattern without a name `{__}` so you can't use it in the right side of the expression. The right way could be:

```
f[{a_,b_}]:= a^2+b^2;
```