# Input list to a pure function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The syntax for a pure function is something like `(1+#1+#2)&[a,b]`, which gives `1+a+b`. Now I want to supply the output from some function which looks like `{a,b}` to the function above, i.e., something like `(1+#1+#2)&{a,b}`, but with the correct syntax, as that obviously doesn't work. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i pass parameters stored in a list to expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176430/how-can-i-pass-parameters-stored-in-a-list-to-expression)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest approach is to use `Apply` (`@@`):

```
In[4]:= (1 + #1 + #2) & @@ {a, b}

Out[4]= 1 + a + b
```

Comment: An alternative is `(1 + ##) & @@ {a, b}` that work with any length of the list.

Answer (score 5):

To provide some alternatives, you can also include the `Apply` within the function if that is more convenient:

```
f = (1 + # + #2) & @@ # &;

f @ {a, b}
```

```
1 + a + b
```

Optionally, you can index parts manually:

```
f = (1 + #[[1]] + #[[2]]) &;
```

Finally, you may already know this, but for others reading this question:

```
g[{x_, y_}] := 1 + x + y

g @ {a, b}
```

```
1 + a + b
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version that is an ordinary function (ie can use square brackets) that will take an arbitrary list. The `Apply` has been moved inside the function and the `##` means `SlotSequence` (c.f. `_` and `__` in pattern matching)

```
In[1]:= (1 + ##&@@ #) &[{a, b}]
        (1 + ##&@@ #) &[{a, b, c, d, e}]

Out[1]= 1 + a + b

Out[2]= 1 + a + b + c + d + e
```

Comment: Its interesting to note that a pure function will accept an infinite number of arguments, and the number of vars in `Function` or the max n in `#n` gives the minimum number of arguments required. However, `##n` does not impose any such minimum.

Comment: @rcollyer are you sure?  Try:  `{##4} & @@@ Array[Range, 5]`

Comment: @Mr, odd. because I'd run some experiments last week with it which seemed to indicate that it worked. back to the drawing board.