# mathematica removes extra curly brakets

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Queried data into mathematica and I got a list/array in the following format

```
x = {{},{},{},{}}
```

I want to plot a LayeredGraphPlot
but I need the data to be as followed 
LayeredGraphPlot[{},{},{}]

How do I remove the out layer of curly bracket 
**{**{},{},{}**}**

Comment: Try [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html): `LayeredGraphPlot@@{{},{},{}}`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i pass parameters stored in a list to expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176430/how-can-i-pass-parameters-stored-in-a-list-to-expression)